# ActionBarView can only be used with android:layout_height="match_parent"

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to design an app with screenshot function.
This is my class:

```
public class ScreenShot {

private static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity activity) {

    View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));  
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());  
    // view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();

    if (null == b1 || b1.getHeight() == 0 || b1.getWidth() == 0) {
        System.out.println("b1 is null");
    } else {
        System.out.println("b1 is NOT null");
    }

    view.destroyDrawingCache();
    return b1;
}


private static void savePic(Bitmap b, String strFileName) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(strFileName);
        if (null != fos) {
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void shoot(Activity a) {  
    File sdcardDir = null;
    boolean isSDExist = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    if (isSDExist) {
        sdcardDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    } else {
        sdcardDir = null;
    }
    String file = sdcardDir + "/xx.png";
    System.out.println(file);
    ScreenShot.savePic(ScreenShot.takeScreenShot(a), file);
    }
}
```

But it has some errors: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarView can only be used with android:layout_height="match_parent"` ;
I don't know why this happend, and I have not used an ActionBarView. My layout just have only a textview and a relativelayout.

There is an error log: `03-03 10:56:09.530: E/AndroidRuntime(20452):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12912)`;May be the `view.measure()` has something wrong I used?

Answer (score 0):

> `View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
>   This will retrieve the top-level window decor view that include actionbar and actionbar only be used with height = match_parent

If you do not want to use the ActionBar you must use a NoActionBar theme (eg Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar)

Or change the value 0 in the code below by -1

> `view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));`

Comment: I have try to change 0 to -1, the errors are there however. But I solve the problem. Using `view.measure` for `view.getDrawingCache()` always return null. I found that the null return come from the layout not load entire, so if I add a button and screenshot in onClickListener, everything is ok. 

But the result is not what I want. So I have to try something else.